# Comparing prediction intervals to find probability of outcome

Tags: predictive-models, prediction-interval, probit

I had a thought I was curious about.  I was reading some of the other posts, but they didn't answer the question specifically.

Say I have a regression y = X'B ~ N(mu,sigma2)

From this regression, I calculate some prediction interval for multiple X.  These intervals *should* be normally distributed if the underlying X's are, correct?

If the prediction intervals are normally distributed and they overlap in some capacity[![1]][1]

How can I calculate the probability of an outcome coming from the blue distribution instead of the red, or vice versa?  Some thoughts have to do with integrating the area that blue and red overlap and subtracting the area that red is below blue, using a cumulative distribution, or just looking at a probit regression and linking that to an OLS of the time.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAp3t.png

Comment: Josh Starmer has a youtube video named "Gaussian Naive Bayes, Clearly Explained". If I understand your question correctly, it might just contain the best answer clearly explained: https://youtu.be/H3EjCKtlVog (his style is unusual - yes, it is serious statistics that he presents).

Comment: I think it answered my question, but I'm not sure I wrapped my head around it all the way.  It seemed to me like it was used for predicting yes or no outcomes, which is not exactly what I was trying to get at.  I'm trying to wrap my head around race time outcomes, and figuring out the probability that the blue runner runs a faster time than the red runner.  The prediction intervals are the estimated times that either runner is capable of running.  I guess my thought was that, where the two distributions overlap, there is a higher probability of the blue runner getting that overlap than red.

Comment: If you want to explain your question in more detail (what it's about and so on) please do not do that in the comments but edit your questions. Not everyone joinging later will necessarily read all the comments. You asked whether a question came from the blue or the red normal distribution. That is a yes/no question. The difference is, that you have one value whereas in the video, there are three values for each proband.